# Totaling Records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that returns the list of sales by customers, but I would like to know just the customer details and total value of sales. The only way I think of being able to do this is to create a second query based on the first one, remove the fields that cause unique records (e.g. description, goods) so I am only left with customer and sale value and then total/group that.

Is that the only way around or can this be done in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this, or you can also copy your existing query, and do the grouping and summing in the copy.

But obviously you need two queries if you want both the full list and the totals query.

**Edit:** If you only need the totals, then edit the original query. Remove the columns you don't need, group by customer, sum the sale values.

Comment: I just want the totals query.

Comment: Not quite sure why I thought that wasn't possible.